# MySQL behaving oddly while inserting rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am seeing an odd behavior of MySQL data base.While inserting a row in database with codeigniter, row is not persist but auto increment field is incremented. I can see increment when I insert a new row. And the worst is that if a insert same data again (submitting form), it get inserted and I can see that data in database.

My code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`first_name`, `country`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `ip_address`, `created_on`, `active`) 
        VALUES('".$adiData['first_name']."', '".$adiData['country']."', '".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."', '".$ip_address."', ".$time.", 1)";
        $this->db->query($sql);
```

- There is no trigger in database and library.
- I have inserted same data from database directly its working fine.
- There is no dependencies,I checked.
- I also checked server details,there is sufficient space.
- CI database function returning success,but row not exist in database.

One more thing which makes me more confuse, yesterday I restart server and insert get fine. and now this morning I am getting same trouble.

Please tell what could be the reason?

Comment: share the table schema..show create table TABLE_NAME;

Comment: there is no error , just data is not persist in database for the first time.

Comment: Use standard CodeIgniter procedure to add records. May be there is invalid character in user input which causing to break the query.

Comment: if this would be the reason,why the same data is inserted next time.

Comment: @AnandSingh make sure your inserted record does not make any duplicate

Comment: exactly that was the problem... not every thing is fine

Comment: Be careful with your queries - this may contain a SQL injection vulnerability. What database engine are you using? If you are using the old PHP `mysql` engine then you should switch to something that is still under maintenance, and use parameter binding.

Comment: Also, whilst I appreciate the question is resolved, there does not seem to be enough detail in the question to work out that you might be getting unique constraint errors. Can we see how your query is getting executed? I wonder if you are running a query but not checking to see if that call succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have unique constraints, data redundancy is a very issue, you must not to make some columns unique or may be composite key, depends on your requirements.

For example:

In case of a user table, the username must be unique so it won't let you insert redundant rows.

Comment: there are two unique column in table and that it self the auto incremented field and email

Comment: can you me the table schema?

Comment: @ Danyal there is an message  " This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Comment: thnx @Danyal ,i will check, add unique to id and email.

Comment: i can help you..go to the database and execute this query : show create table your_table_name.. it will show you table schema..paste it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93565/discussion-between-anand-singh-and-danyal-sandeelo).

Comment: its workiing fine now,,, thanx alot Danyal. :) if you explain the reason it would be gr8.

Comment: you didn't add the constraints property that's why i guess.

Comment: Again its happening.. please help if possible.  table schema https://unsee.cc/pumeraso/

Comment: execute this query : show create table your_table_name  and paste the output here

Answer (score 0):

Try using in codeigniter way
For ex.

```
// get data from form
    $data = array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                    'contact'=>$this->input->post('contact'),
                    'address'=>$this->input->post('address')
            );
     $this->db->insert('tableName',$data);
```

For more read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-beginner-guide/

Comment: previously i used that... there is no issue regarding functions of Ci.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter Insert Method

```
$data = array(
            'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'country'       => $this->input->post('country'),
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $password,
            'email'         => $email,
            'ip_address'    => $ip_address,
            'time'          => $time,

    );
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

and in `config/database.php`

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';//MySQL Username
$db['default']['password'] = '';//MySQL Password
$db['default']['database'] = '';//db name
```

and in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

> ***Make Sure variables are not empty***

**EDIT 01**

Goto

1. Phpmyadmin
2. select your `database`, then go to `users` table.
3. Click `structure` on top.
4. Click `Change`, in front of `id` field.
5. Then there is check box with **AI(Auto Increment)**
6. ***Check that and click save***

Comment: thnx for you answer but,i have been telling that, i tried all the insert method of CI and i know how to use database library ,Please tell what could make increment in database without inserting data.

Comment: increment database mean?? auto increment id ??

Comment: increment in auto increment field,,, please check my question.

Comment: i am glad to see your support, thnx. @ Abdulla .Actually its already an auto incremented field,I was asking for the reason "Why in database auto increment counter is incremented without inserting row in table". Sorry if i was not clear. :)

Comment: ahh if you refresh ur broswer after insert it will add another row. Got it ?? you want know how to prevent that ?? is it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93566/discussion-between-anand-singh-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your createdOn field type is set to datetime, and check the format of the data being passed to this field. If the datetime is not in correct format you may face this issue.

Comment: Also echo your query and run it manually in the phpmyadmin to see if it works, Further you can put try catch or if to get the errors or warnings.

Comment: i have tried this.. and its working fine. no problem in that.